# Can anyone explain this answer? - python

Tags: python

This is the code segment

```
values_a = [1, -5, 2, 0, 4, 2, -3]
values_b = [1, -5, 2, 4, 4, 2, 7]
answer = 0
for position in range(len(values_a)):
    if values_a[position] != values_b[position]:
        answer = answer + 1

print answer
```

the answer is 2 and i don't get why
isn't this meant to be 1?

Comment: Why would it be 1? It counts pairs (items at same position) that are different. 0 is different from 4, and -3 is different from 7, which is two different pairs.

Comment: Can you please explain why you expect the answer to be 1?

Answer (score 3):

Because two values differ:

```
values_a = [1, -5, 2, 0, 4, 2, -3]
values_b = [1, -5, 2, 4, 4, 2,  7]

                      ^         ^
                      |         |____ boom!
                      |
                      ______ boom!

0 + 2 == 2
```